# MySQL Join using "contains"?

Tags: mysql, join

I have these two tables:

```
Table: ORDERS
ID - NAME    - DATA
---------------------------------------------
1  - Order 1 - node_checkout_nid";i:141;s:10:
2  - Order 2 - node_checkout_nid";i:142;s:10:

Table: NODES
NID - Description
--------------------
141 - bla bla bla
142 - bla bla bla 2
```

I need a SQL join query that can join the two tables on NID, keeping in mind the NID is in the "DATA" column.

I need to end with this:

```
Table: RESULT
ID - NAME    - DATA                             NID - Description
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  - Order 1 - node_checkout_nid";i:141;s:10: - 141 - bla bla bla
2  - Order 2 - node_checkout_nid";i:142;s:10: - 142 - bla bla bla 2
```

I wanted to use a "like" join, but I think (if it's possible) a "contains" join would be better? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Stop storing multiple serialized values in one column!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, DATA, NID, Description
  FROM ORDERS INNER JOIN NODES ON DATA LIKE CONCAT('%;i:', NID, ';%')
```

Anyway it's a heavy query. It's not a good idea to have the NID inside the data field as a plain text, better in a different column.

Comment: Now you just need to pray, that NID is not equal to say `10` .

Comment: @Mchl: Thanks to fix it, I saw the error but when I tried to access to fix it, I couldn't :(

Comment: And it's true, you need to look for the NID, in the correct place. I fix the query with this

Answer (score 2):

You data is denormalised. You're storing some serialized object in `DATA` column and are trying to perform relational operations basing on that. While it is possible to do so, mind that it will be slow and potentially unreliable. Just store your NID in a separate column.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option for me. I know it's supposed to be in a seperate column, but due to various structural limitations, this can't be done.